# Suddenly getting "Check Signal Cable" when using external monitor with MacBook Pro

Tags: external-display

I have a VGA cable that I hook up from mac to the external monitor to make dual monitors. This used to work all the time but now when I connect them together it says "Check Signal Cable" what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your vga cable might have a problem is there another machine that you can test the monitor with?

that's the best way to determine whether the problem is with the monitor or cable.

Comment: That, or hitting some magic key on the Mac to enable the external output. (F7 on my old MacBook.)